# A non-UFD $B$ such that $A \subset B \subset C$, where $A \cong C$ are UFD's

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, prime-factorization, unique-factorization-domains

Let $A \subset C$ be two isomorphic unique factorization domains (UFD's).

> Is it possible to find an integral domain $B$, $A \subset B \subset C$,
>   such that $B$ is not a UFD?

I have tried to construct the following counterexample (but have not succeeded): $A=\mathbb{C}[p,q]$, $C=\mathbb{C}[x,y]$,
where $p,q \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ are algebraically independent over $\mathbb{C}$
(this is equivalent to $\{p,q\}$ having a non-zero Jacobian: $p_xq_y-p_yq_x \neq 0$), and $B=\mathbb{C}[p,q][w]$, for some $w \in \mathbb{C}$, but the problem is to find concrete $p,q,w$ such that $B$ is not a UFD and not equals either $A$ or $C$.

Perhaps the following is a counterexample: $A=k[x_2,x_3,\ldots]$, $B=k[x_1^2,x_1^3,x_2,x_3,\ldots]$, $C=k[x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots]$?

Related ideas (perhaps I should elaborate why they are relevent) are :
 [Nagata's criterion for factoriality](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0AFU) and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1521574/integral-domain-without-prime-elements-which-is-not-a-field/1521597#1521597).

Any ideas are welcome!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

Let $K$ be a field, and let
\begin{align*}
C &= K[x]\qquad\qquad\qquad\;\,\\[4pt]
B &= K[x^2,x^3]\\[4pt]
A &= K[x^6]\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
Then
\begin{align*}
&{\small{\bullet}}\;\;A \subset B \subset C\\[4pt]
&{\small{\bullet}}\;\;A,C\;\text{are isomorphic UFDs}\\[4pt]
&{\small{\bullet}}\;\;B\;\text{is not a UFD}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

To see that $B$ is not a UFD, note that in $B$, the elements $x^2$ and $x^3$ are distinct irreducibles, so

$$(x^2)(x^2)(x^2) = x^6 = (x^3)(x^3)$$

gives two distinct factorizations of $x^6$ into irreducibles.

Hence, as claimed, $B$ is not a UFD.

Comment: Because $x^6$ factors as $(x^2)^3$ and also as $(x^3)^2$.

Comment: Please, what do you say about my counterexample (which I have added 4 minutes ago)? It's okay, isn't it?

Comment: Truly, I am interested to know if there exists such $B$ for the specific $A=\mathbb{C}[p,q]$ and $C=\mathbb{C}[x,y]$, but because I did not mention this explicitly in my question, I accepted the above (nice and easy) answer.

Comment: What are $p,q$? Are they elements of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$?

Comment: Yes, and they are algebraically independent over $\mathbb{C}$ in order to get $\mathbb{C}[p,q] \cong \mathbb{C}[x,y]$.

Comment: Do I get to choose $p,q$?

Comment: Yes, but I prefer to further assume that their Jacobian $p_xq_y-p_yq_x$ belongs to $\mathbb{C}-\{0\}$, not just to $\mathbb{C}[x,y]-\{0\}$. (Recall that: $\{p,q\}$ are algebraically independent over $\mathbb{C}$ iff their Jacobian is non-zero). But if you have found such $B$ for $\{p,q\}$ having just non-zero Jacobian (probably in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]-\mathbb{C}$), this is also interesting (though a little less interesting).

Comment: If the Jacobian conjecture is true, the condition $p_xq_y-p_yq_x \in \mathbb{C}-\{0\}$ would imply $\mathbb{C}[p,q]=\mathbb{C}[x,y]$, so there's nowhere to put $B$.

Comment: Exactly...but it is still open (though I 'believe' it is true, at least for polynomials in two variables).

Comment: This is why I 'conjecture' that there is no such $B$. If I am not wrong, answering my question in the positive (=there is no such $B$) is equivalent to the two-dimensional JC... Since then $\mathbb{C}[p,q,x]$ is a UFD, and in this case it is possible to show that $f: (x,y) \mapsto (p,q)$ is an automorphism...